# Changing legend symbol ggplot2 with multiple legends

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a graph like attached and want to change the 'colour' legend to be a symbol of a square or circle not a line.
[image: graph]

```html
    ggplot(sharkanovadata, aes(x=mean, y=sd), colour="Sharks")+
  geom_point(alpha=0.2)+
  geom_point(data=birdanovadata, colour= "#D22B2B", alpha=0.1)+
  geom_abline(data=sharkanovadata, mapping=aes(colour="Sharks", slope=0.15, intercept=3.33, linetype= "Genetic"), size=1.2)+
  geom_abline(data=sharkanovadata, mapping= aes( colour="Sharks", slope= 0.22, intercept=4.12, linetype= "Imputed"), size=1.2) +
  geom_abline(data=birdanovadata, mapping=aes(colour= "Birds", slope=0.17, intercept=0.31, linetype= "Genetic"), size=1.2)+
  geom_abline(data=birdanovadata, mapping=aes(colour= "Birds", slope=0.30, intercept=0.53, linetype="Imputed"), size=1.2)+
  scale_colour_manual(values= c("Sharks" = "black", "Birds" = "#B03A2E"))+
  xlab("Mean ED") +
  ylab("Standard deviation of ED") +
  ggtitle("Imputed species have a greater linear relationship of standard devation and mean", (size=30))+ 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(size=0.4, colour= "grey"))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values= c("Genetic"= "longdash", "Imputed" = "solid"))+
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(1, 'cm')) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

Answer (score 2):

As the legend symbols aka key glyphs are determined by the `geom`s one option would be to switch the `key_glyph` for one of your `geom_abline`s. to `point` which will add a point to each legend. Afterwards we can tweak the the `color` and `linetype` legends via the `override.aes` argument of `guide_legend` where I opted for a square shape.

As you provided no data I use some fake random data to mimic your real data:

```r
set.seed(123)

birdanovadata <- sharkanovadata <- data.frame(
  mean = runif(1000, 0, 150),
  sd = runif(1000, 0, 30)
)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(sharkanovadata, aes(x = mean, y = sd), colour = "Sharks") +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_point(data = birdanovadata, colour = "#D22B2B", alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_abline(data = sharkanovadata, mapping = aes(colour = "Sharks", slope = 0.15, intercept = 3.33, linetype = "Genetic"), size = 1.2, key_glyph = "point") +
  geom_abline(data = sharkanovadata, mapping = aes(colour = "Sharks", slope = 0.22, intercept = 4.12, linetype = "Imputed"), size = 1.2) +
  geom_abline(data = birdanovadata, mapping = aes(colour = "Birds", slope = 0.17, intercept = 0.31, linetype = "Genetic"), size = 1.2) +
  geom_abline(data = birdanovadata, mapping = aes(colour = "Birds", slope = 0.30, intercept = 0.53, linetype = "Imputed"), size = 1.2) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("Sharks" = "black", "Birds" = "#B03A2E")) +
  xlab("Mean ED") +
  ylab("Standard deviation of ED") +
  ggtitle("Imputed species have a greater linear relationship of standard devation and mean", (size <- 30)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.4, colour = "grey")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("Genetic" = "longdash", "Imputed" = "solid")) +
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = "blank", size = 8, shape = 15)), 
         linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = NA)))
```

[image]